# Normalizing a list of restaurant dishes

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I have a large data set of restaurant dishes (for example, "Pulled Pork", "Beef Brisket"...)

I am trying to "normalize" (wrong word) the dishes. I want "Pulled Pork" and "Pulled Pork Sandwich" and "Jumbo Pork Slider" all to map to a single dish, "Pulled Pork".

So far I have gotten started with NLTK using Python and had some fun playing around with frequency distributions and such.

Does anyone have a high-level strategy to approach this problem? Perhaps some keywords I could google?

Thanks

Comment: It seems like the common elements in the "pulled pork" list is the word "pork". I would be tempted to find the n most common words (you may want to filter out nouns specifically) in the dataset of dishes, then find subsets of dishes (which may overlap) that contain specific common words.

Comment: Try hyper/hyponym generation, see alt.qcri.org/semeval2015/task17/ and shameless plug: http://aclanthology.info/papers/usaar-wlv-hypernym-generation-with-deep-neural-nets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want look for `TFIDF` and `cosine similarity`.

There are challenging cases, however. Let's say you have the following three dishes:

- Pulled pork
- Pulled egg
- Egg sandwich

Which of the two you are going to combine?

- Pulled pork and pulled egg
- Pulled egg and egg sandwich

Using `TFIDF`, you can find the most *representative*  words. For example the word *sandwich* may happen to be in many dishes, hence not very *representative*. (Tuna sandwich, egg sandwich, cheese sandwich, etc.) Merging tuna sandwich and cheese sandwich may not be a good idea.

After you have the TFIDF vectors, you can use cosine similarity (using the TFIDF vectors) and maybe a static threshold, you can decide whether to merge them or not.

There is also another issue arises: When you match, what are you going to name them? (Pulled egg or egg sandwich?)

### Update:

@alvas suggests to use clustering after having the similarity/dissimilarity values. I think that would be good idea. You can first create your `nxn` distance/similarity matrix using the cosine similarity with TFIDF vectors. And after you have the distance matrix, you can cluster them using a clustering algorithm.

Comment: This is hypothetical and not real truth, you will face more noise when you do cosine-similarity especially when you decide where is the threshold to decide what is "similar" and what is your gold cluster. A clustering approach would be more appropriate.

Comment: @alvas I would actually agree with that. The OP seemed to find a fast/ad-hoc solution to this problem, that is why I was thinking about a static-threshold. Probably, clustering the cosine similarities (similarity/distance matrix) would a more former/better way of doing it. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, guys. This seems like a great approach.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are effectively trying to do [coreference resolution](http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/coref.shtml) on named entities, where the entities are distinct dishes.  You can check out projects like [`cort`](https://github.com/smartschat/cort) and [`nltk-drt`](https://code.google.com/p/nltk-drt/).

However, from your example it's a little unclear why a pulled pork sandwich should be considered the same dish as pulled pork, so you may need a way to come up with your own training set (e.g. culled from google) that tags entities as distinct within your desired tolerance.